# How to auto-resize a smaller image to fit a large div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit a small image into a larger div.

```css
html, body {

height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

/*About Us Page*/
    .bgimage {
        width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: relative;
    }

    img {

        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
    }

    #aboutus {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        background-color: rgb(82, 63, 51);
        
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border-style: groove;
        border-color: rgb(75, 58, 36);
        border-width: 20px;
        

        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>The Hewitt's Den: About Us</title>
        
        <style>
          
#aboutus {

  text-align: center;
}

        </style>
      </head>
 <body>

<div class="bgimage">
      <div class="navi">
        <img class="AboutUsPic" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/gray-white-gradient-abstract-background_53876-60238.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="aboutus">
<h1>About Us:</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
 </body>
        </html>
```

The image is too small to fit into the div, I could manually change the size of the image, but I want it to automatically fit, to accommodate other screen sizes. If it's possible, maybe it could maintain it's width-height size, to avoid looking stretched or compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `img` elements use [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and in your case like this:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

`object-fit` only works if you make the `img` element capture the full dimensions first - full width of its parent `div` in this case.

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-franklin-isc9b?file=/styles.css:187-276)

Comment: I neglected to write that this isn't for all the images, but for the img class "AboutUsPic" (You have probably figured this out yourself, though. Is there any change needed to be made to the solution? (Apart from the "img" to ".AboutUsPic")

Comment: @Vexxed58 No problem :) No other change is required for it to work. Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

CSS background-image
background-size: cover

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: This is for background images using only CSS which in this case the question includes a `<img>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use property ***width: 100%*** for image element like this:

```
img {
    width: 100%
}
```